# Mac OS X Terminal: Commands not found

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I really don't have much experience with Terminal and I believe I may have caused a problem when trying to download and use [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) on my Mac. If I try to type in anything I simply get "Command not found". After reading many forum posts I believe this has something to do with my PATH, but again, I don't really know exactly what that means.

Comment: Yes, your PATH variable, in simple terms, controls what commands can be found. Try typing `echo $PATH` and update your question with the result.

Comment: Could you expand on 'anything'? What exactly are you trying?

Comment: Okay, this is what I get when I type that: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:PATHnexport

Comment: @Shaun I was trying to use Wine in order to run windows programs. I used instructions from (http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/) but I believe I may have done something incorrectly and possibly damaged my system

Comment: It looks like you have indeed messed something up. At the least, you should have the system standard paths `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` in there. The `PATHnexport` bit at the end looks very wrong. Which steps from the link you have sent have you followed? I suspect you might have broken your `/etc/profile` file (Step 2.1). Might help if you can paste the end of that file in (careful not to paste any private info).

Comment: I type that in and it says "-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied". I'm the only user on my laptop...

Comment: @JaredGross, `/etc/profile` should be readable by every user. You can fix that with `sudo chmod a+r /etc/profile`. That might even fix your problem if you do that and then log out/log in. Careful, you're playing with the guts of your system here, so type carefully and don't do anything you're uncertain about.

Comment: Well there's the core of my problem. I type that in and I get, "-bash: sudo: command not found". Thank you for helping by the way.

Comment: Well, you are getting that because your PATH is set wrong :) You can always provide the full path to commands like this instead: `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: Oh it asked me for a password that time! Then it said "sudo: chmod: command not found". Here's what I typed in which may have been incorrect, "/usr/bin/sudo chmod a+r /etc/profile"

Comment: Apply a similar principle: `/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod a+r /etc/profile`. Assuming that works, restart your system for good measure afterward.

Comment: was anything supposed to happen after I that? I got nothing...so did it work?

Comment: Yes, it did. There will only be output if it fails.

Comment: Okay, so then is there a way to see if I've resolved anything? My PATH doesn't seem to have changed

Comment: @JaredGross, rebooting your system will definitely surface the changes in /etc/profile, although even logging out and in will probably suffice. Even so, remember the original objective was to check what changes you'd made to /etc/profile - it might be that, or it might just be the broken permissions.

Comment: After restarting I still get the same permission denied message.

Comment: I would move  ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile to another directory - It is likely you misedited one of these files

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the link and also your path it looks like you have installed Macports. Its installer will change in ~/.profile the path but not in the way you show. See [macports document](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts#a3.Settheshellenvironment) for the correct way to do this.

Editing /etc/profile is not the correct way as it affects all users and is also more complex to deal with as requires root permission and is also an Apple supplied file that could be changed in Apple system upgrades

This explains two of your /opt/local/bin ... etc in your path (/etc/profile and ~/.profile) More and the `PATHnexport` imply that yor editing of files has gone wrong.

I would restore /etc/profile from a backup to be as Apple set it up, and check that .profile has the lines as per the macports document. Also check to see if you have ~/.bash_profile or ~/.login and check they do not have any alterations to the PATH

If you are not used to Terminal (e.g. if you do not understand what these .profile files are) then it mght be better to install wine via a GUI method e.g. [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php) or [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) (Even if you do understand Terminal and shells t is easier to use these)

Comment: As you guessed, I don't know what those profiles are or exactly how to restore them from a backup. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Really a separate question - first question is how do you backup now?