# Mavericks Terminal - 'Command Not Found' for everything

Tags: macos, terminal

About everything (even clear and open) is giving 'Command Not Found' on the Terminal.

If I do and echo $PATH, it gives me this.
/Users/username/Documents/android/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/merck/Documents/android/android-sdk-macosx/tools

The /.profile file is not even there in the Finder.

The environment.plist file in .MacOSX has this value.
bplist00—_SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0_$/Users/username/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67E

Can anyone give some pointers.

Comment: There are already several questions covering situations like this, for instance http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69721/mac-os-x-terminal-commands-not-found and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83024/terminal-returns-not-found-for-most-commands-mac-osx. Can you please try the answers listed there first? If this doesn't solve your problem, please edit the things you've unsuccessfully tried into the question and have it reopened.

Answer (score -1):

Look in the .bashrc file, and see if anything towards the end is overwriting (rather than appending to) the $PATH ...

I am guessing that the Android SDK b0rked it somehow.